# Lookup and filter data inOracle SQL

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a requierment where I need to filter some of the records for finance in oracle:
I tried self join and this is my code:

```
select distinct  
a.BILLNO, a.debcred,a.voucher  ,a.amount 
from cte a,cte b
where a.amount<>(b.amount*-1)and a.billno=b.billno(+)
and  (a.debcred='C' and b.debcred='D')
```

my code is unable to fetch the records where we don't have both 'C' and 'D' entries in the table.

[image]

[image]

Really appreciate your help!

Comment: What should be the desired output?

Comment: the second attachment (output)

Comment: isn't that the current output which you don't want to get?

Comment: The one above  is the expected output .Sorry for the confusion.I am getting the Top 2 row of the output not the last one(company =123 )

Comment: When I pick the first picture as the input data, [those three rows return](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8e7d3da6d5cf26e3350b2238cda07638) from the current query.

Comment: The amount in your output you have on the output does not match with my expected output

Comment: I didn't attempt to solve the question yet, just converted to a demonstration in order to understand what exactly you need. Btw, showed the current output shouldn't be as in the 2nd picture, if the first one is input.